Are faster punches more powerful in boxing?
I train and spar in boxing, and am an avid follower of professional fights as well. I've heard almost every coach, other boxer, commentators, and so on refer to "Mayweather is has insane speed, but Oscar De La Hoya is more of a power puncher", and things such as "Focus on speed this round, not power" from my coach.
I THINK I get what they are saying, but I got an A+ in Physics class and a cursory reminder definition of Power:

In physics, power is the amount of energy transferred or converted per
unit time.

This confuses me, because by that definition, reducing unit time, aka "speeding up", should INCREASE power. That is, power itself is a function of speed (more precisely, of time). Increasing the speed implies decreasing the time and decreasing the time can increase the power because it decreases the denominator. When I "snap"/"pop" my punches out and back, aren't they actually more powerful? If not, could you please elaborate why not? I'm wondering if when these people are saying "power" they actually mean "amount of force behind the punch?" Is power misused here or am I just totally confused?

In addition to speed, you can change mass. You can land a punch with just the mass of your hand (a jab), or you can land a punch with all of your body's mass (a haymaker). As mass is resistance to acceleration, you can more easily land a fast punch with less mass behind it.
When someone tells you to "focus on speed rather than power", it means you should sacrifice mass to increase speed.

So, does the advice of "focus on speed rather than power" mean "put less mass into the punch?" typically?

@the_endian Aye, like you can flick a jab (speed) vs. you can put a bit rotation and shift of your center behind it. The former will be much faster, the latter will have more power. Generally, the more your punches involve significant footwork and lower body movement, the more power they will be able to generate as maximal potential. Of course, pro boxers will be able to generate insane power with almost nothing of what I mention. That's why they are pro boxers. Note regarding physics: power in martial arts usually means impulse, ie. how much the hit accelerates the opponent's body parts.

I get a bit muddled when I talk to much about this physics stuff, but I'll do my best to explain it to you anyway.
To land your most powerful punch, you'll typically wind up a bit, so to speak, and accelerate your hand over a longer distance.
Let's take a look at the formula for the energy of a boxing punch:
Ekin = 2m × s²/t².
The formula shows us that:
The mass of the arm and glove is represented by m. There's no way around it other than using your whole body for the punching motion, turning your hips with the punch. Which is what @mattm is talking about.

s is the distance the fist travels. You can change this by "winding" up the punch, which gives it a longer distance to travel.
t is the time it takes to make the punch.

The key thing to note is the s²: The distance is squared. This means that every extra bit of distance adds more force than you'd expect.
If you double the distance, you quadruple the impact force. If you triple the distance, you nine times the impact force.

Now, let's get to your question. Are faster punches more powerful?
What does "more powerful" mean here? Is it about having more kinetic energy or being more useful to win the battle?
What does "faster punch" mean? Is it about the velocity of the fist at the end of the punch or punches in a higher frequency?
A "fast punch" could be:

"low" in energy (light punch) but in a rapid succession
"high" in energy (hard punch) but in slow frequency

I have to take a brake now, but let me know if that helps ;)
